# Does there exist a prime that is a sum of two prime power towers?

Tags: prime-numbers, power-towers

Does there exist prime number of the form
$$\huge 2^{3^{5^{\,.^{.^{.\,^{p_n}}}}}} + p_n^{p_{n-1}^{\,.^{.^{.\,^{3^{2}}}}}}$$
where $p_n$ is the $n$-th prime number(and both towers are running through the first $n$ primes in order), other than the trivial one
$$2^3+3^2=17$$
This number that is the sum of two power towers of first $n$ primes is more than just extremely difficult, it is insanely difficult to become a prime, because if the lower towers divisible by say $k$, then the main number is also divisible by $k$. For example
$$\Large 2^{3^5}+11^{7^5} \qquad\qquad 2^{3^{5^7}}+11^{7^{5^3}}$$ $2^{3^{5^{7}}}+11^{7^5}$, are all divisible by $23$, and so is
$$\Large 2^{3^{5^{7^{11}}}}+11^{7^{5^{3^2}}}$$
So **does there exist a prime number** of this form other than the trivial one $2^3+3^2$?

Comment: Why is it true that "if the lower tower's divisible by say $k$, then the main number is also divisible by $k$"?

Comment: @vadim123 you can observe it yourself ,it is easy to check it

Comment: If it is easy, please provide the proof.  It is not enough to observe it holds for several examples.

Comment: It's not true. The first tower is only divisible by two, and the other is odd.

Comment: Please format that question using Latex, and don't caps-lock to ask your questions.

Do you have any other work on the problem besides experimentation?

Only the last example you gave is actually of the form you mentioned. The example $2^{3^5} + 11^{7^5}$ isn't in that form.

Comment: @CuddlyCuttlefish I never said the number of towers of both sides must equal

Comment: As @vadim123 said many of your claims here are false. Also, numbers don't just "become" primes. What do you mean by "difficult"?

Comment: @LinusS. I meant this number is always composites

Comment: Someone's edited your post to make it readable. How come you changed it back?

Comment: @LinusS. No it's an accident, I didn't rool back it

Comment: Following on your comment to @CuddlyCuttlefish your use of $n$ in both towers indicates that they are the same height and the same terms.  If that is not your intent, you should use different variables.  Your example with $n=2$ supports this.  We need to know what flexibility is there.  Can I make the right tower just $2$ or $9$?

Comment: @RossMillikan No you've misunderstood it, I mean the main number IS WITH THE SAME NUMBER OF TOWERS,Because it is FIRST N PRIMES

Comment: @ArnoldDann You're plainly just being unclear, actually.
A power tower is the entire $2^{3^5}$. What is a "main number"? Is a main number a power tower? The use of the same variable implies that they should have the same terms in reverse order. You should change the variables because it is unclear.

Comment: I mean MAIN NUMBER = the original number

Comment: It seems clear that the first term starts with $2$ and runs through the primes in order. As expressed in the question, the second term should have the same height, with the same primes in reverse order.  Your comments indicate there is more flexibility, but do not make clear what that flexibility is. Is the second tower the same height as the first, just starting with a larger prime than the top of the first?  Can it be a different height tower?  Can it even be $2$ (which fails-both terms are even) or $3^2=9?$

Comment: @RossMillikan Yes both towers run through the first n primes in order 2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,......for example: 2^3^5^7^11^13^17+17^13^11^7^5^3^2

Comment: The reason I asked is that you show $2^{3^5}+11^{7^5}$ in the question. If that is not germane, it is a distraction.

Comment: Your examples do not fit the pattern.  The next is $2^{3^5}+5^{3^2}=14134776518227074636666380005943348126619871175004951664972849610342911333$

Comment: @RossMillikan ,please see the example in that question one more time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is quite unlikely there are any more.  $2^{3^5}+5^{3^2}$ has many factors, including $7$.  The first tower dominates the second in size.  Using the chance that a number $n$ is prime is $\frac 1{\log n}$, the first candidate has a chance $\frac{1}{3^{5^7}\log 2} \approx 10^{-37274.93885043456}$  The later terms will decrease so fast the sum will not differ from this by an amount you can see.